# Why fa fa instagram 3x doesn't isn't working?

Tags: css, hover, instagram

I have create some social button. All button are showing except Instagram. I don't know why it is not working. Here is my code

```
<div class="text-center center-block">
                <a href="https://www.facebook.com/shahin.albd"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>

                <a href="https://instagram.com"><i id="social-in" class="fa fa-instagram-square fa-3x social"></i></a>

                <a href="https://twitter.com"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>                
            </div>
```

Here is my CSS for id "social-in"

```
#lab_social_icon_footer #social-in:hover {
```

color: #4E433C;

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `<i id="social-in" class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x social" aria-hidden="true"></i>` . The square feature you're looking for in the background is applied by default. Check the output.

```css
#social-in:hover {
  color: #4E433C;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.2.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<div class="text-center center-block">
  <a href="https://www.facebook.com/shahin.albd"><i id="social-fb" class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-3x social"></i></a>

  <a href="https://instagram.com"><i id="social-in" class="fa fa-instagram fa-3x social" aria-hidden="true"></i></a>

  <a href="https://twitter.com"><i id="social-tw" class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-3x social"></i></a>
</div>
```

Comment: In order for the snippet to run, you need to change the `href` protocol to `https://` in the `link` tag. SO doesn't allow `http` links

Comment: @MosharofHossain No problem :) Make sure to rate or accept the answer which you found helpful or solved your query. Cheers

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome doesn't have an `fa-instagram-square` Icon. They only have `fa-instagram` Available.

However, you can stack this icon with a square Icon, like so:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<span class="fa-stack fa-3x">
    <i class="fa fa-square fa-stack-2x"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-instagram fa-stack-1x" style="color: white;"></i>
</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

FontAwesome don't have instagram-square. Is not necessary because the instagram icon is square. Just remove square and will works.